# Determining if a sequence with varying odd and even terms converges

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

$1/2-1/3+1/4-1/3^2+1/6-1/3^3+1/8-1/3^4+1/10-1/3^5+1/12-1/3^6......$

I think this sequence diverges since $S_{2n}$ approaches 0 faster than $S_{2n}$ so the positive terms will diverge to infinity but i am not certain.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test

Comment: Your intuition is correct: this series is divergent since the positive terms sum up to $+ \infty$, while the negative terms converge to some finite number.

Answer (score 2):

Your series can be written as
$$\frac{1}{2}(1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\cdots)-\frac{1/3}{1-1/3}$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}(1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\cdots)-\frac{1}{2}$$
So you can see it diverges as $(1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\cdots)$ diverges